# Canonical File Path in Ruby

Tags: ruby, path

Is there an easy way in Ruby to find a canonical file path out of a messy file path?

For example:

- `a/b/../c/x` is the same as `a/c/x`
- `a/./b/c/x` is the same as `a/b/c/x`
- `a/./b/../../c/x` is the same as `c/x`

Any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new("a/b/../c/x").cleanpath
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of symlinks too (like Qt's `canonicalFilePath`) then use `realpath` instead of `cleanpath`.

Comment: @Erik You should be aware that `realpath`, unlike `cleanpath`, accesses the filesystem and fails if the path does not exist.

Answer (score 32):

**File.expand_path(file_name [, dir_string] ) → abs_file_name**

Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname. Relative paths are referenced from the current working directory of the process unless dir_string is given, in which case it will be used as the starting point. The given pathname may start with a `~`, which expands to the process owner‘s home directory (the environment variable `HOME` must be set correctly). `~user` expands to the named user‘s home directory.

```
File.expand_path("~oracle/bin")           #=> "/home/oracle/bin"
File.expand_path("../../bin", "/tmp/x")   #=> "/bin"
```

Comment: If you don't need the tilde expansion, use `File.realpath` instead.